# Is the following a quote from Nietzsche?

Tags: reference-request, nietzsche, quote

Hello everyone on PhilStackexchange,

I am just requesting source for a line I heard from a friend who alleges that it is from Nietzsche. The line goes like '*he who leaves me is my true follower*', and I remember him attributing it to Nietzsche's Zarathustra book. Is the quote (google does not show any result when this line is searched up in verbatim form -- often for quotes not originally written in English) authentic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Friedrich Nietzsche, [Thus Spoke Zarathustra: A Book for All and None (German: *Also sprach Zarathustra: Ein Buch für Alle und Keinen*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thus_Spoke_Zarathustra) (1883-91), [First part](https://books.google.it/books?id=sMHmCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA68) :

> "Alone I go now, my disciples! You too must go away, now, and alone. Thus I will it.
>
> [...] Go away from me and guard yourselves against Zarathustra! And better still: be ashamed of him! Perhaps he has deceived you. [...]
>
> Now I bid you lose me and find yourselves; and only when you have all denied me will I return to you."